# mininet_wifi iperf cannot be set

Tags: python, mininet, iperf

Trying to iperf host and a client (station) with the following code, while the iperf does not work.
Anyone?

import sys

from mininet.log import setLogLevel, info
from mn_wifi.net import Mininet_wifi

def topology(args):

```
net = Mininet_wifi()

info("*** Creating nodes\n")
ap1 = net.addAccessPoint('ap1', ssid='new-ssid', mode='g', channel='1', failMode="standalone", mac='00:00:00:00:00:01', position='50,50,0')
net.addStation('sta1', mac='00:00:00:00:00:02', ip='10.0.0.1/8', position='30,60,0')
h1 = net.addHost('h1', ip='10.0.0.3/8')

info("*** Configuring propagation model\n")
net.setPropagationModel(model="logDistance", exp=4.5)

info("*** Configuring wifi nodes\n")
net.configureWifiNodes()

info("*** Creating links\n")
net.addLink(ap1, h1)

info("*** Starting network\n")
net.build()
ap1.start([])

net.iperf(hosts = [ ap1, h1 ], l4Type='TCP', udpBw='10M', fmt=None, seconds=2, port=800)

info("*** Stopping network\n")
net.stop()
```

topology(sys.argv)

The result is as follows:
sudo python examples/_position.py
*** Creating nodes
*** Configuring propagation model
*** Configuring wifi nodes
*** Creating links
*** Starting network
*** Iperf: testing TCP bandwidth between ap1 and h1 => which never goes off

Answer (score 1):

`ap1` has no ip address. You cannot ping (neither use Iperf) to a device that has no ip address. Moreover, OVS won't work for your purpose. This means that you need to use UserAP (ofsoftswitch13) instead of OVS and the ap should be running in its network namespace.